# Can I export dmp file with Oracle jobs?

Tags: oracle, oracle11g

Now I'm too keen to know how can I export dmp file with Oracle jobs? It's because of I'm very new to Oracle and don't know how to backup Oracle with jobs like MsSQL bachup with schedule. That's why I want to know what I asked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can fairly easy setup a backup scheduled by the database. Best approach for this is to install the Oracle Scheduler Remote Job Agent - local to the database - and configure that agent in the database that holds your backup schedule. This can be the database itself, it can also be a central backup schedule database, all a matter of taste.

Oracle Scheduler is very powerful and can execute tasks in the local database, in remote database[s], on the local server and on remote servers. If using OS type of jobs, best is to use the 11g Remote Scheduler Agent. **Don't use the old fashioned 10g style External Jobs**. Use remote jobs with defined credentials.

For help look at [my blog](http://ronr.blogspot.com/2009/10/oracle-scheduler-in-11gr2-p2-schagent.html) where you also find pointers to docu.

After you installed and configured the job agent to be a valid target for the database that performs the scheduling, easiest is to use dbconsole to define the jobs. If you configure the dbconsole, it also gives an option to generate auto backup jobs. Maybe this is already enough. You asked for export and there expdp with the Oracle Scheduler does a wonderful job.

Answer (score 1):

You can run an OS process from Oracle Job using Java Stored Procedure or a C program.

See [this blog entry](http://www.toadworld.com/Blogs/tabid/67/EntryId/228/How-to-Run-an-OS-Command-from-PL-SQL.aspx),

Answer (score 0):

Instead of exporting dump using the old imp/exp utilities to generate dmp files, look at Oracle [Datapump](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14215/dp_export.htm), especially since from the tags I infer you're using Oracle 11g.

Data pump supports table-level, tablespace-level, schema-level & full export modes and is kown to be consdirably faster than the previous imp/emp tools.
Further reading:

- [Export/import with Oracle Data pump](http://www.techrepublic.com/article/export-or-import-with-oracle-data-pump/5800445)
- [Oracle Documentation on Data pump](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14215/dp_export.htm)

---

> know how can I export dmp file with Oracle jobs?

That's not possible. The emp tools runs *outside* the database, while jobs run within. if you want scheduled exports perhaps you could use a cronjob/scheduled task.

Comment: I know how to manually export/import Oracle dmp. What I want is to export/import Oracle dmp with Oracle jobs.

Comment: @ppshein That's not possible.

Comment: so can you tell me how to backup Oracle schema/database with schedule and how to restore it again? Thanks.

Comment: @Sathya : it is possible very well to run OS tools using the Oracle Scheduler. The Oracle Scheduler now - since 11g - has a remote job agent, that can also be used local, that can do what's needed and for which it has the correct credentials.

Comment: @ik_zelf Do post that as an answer.

Comment: @ik_zelf Can you post it as answer?